# Wrong import path after building vue proect as a "Library"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I am currently coding a small vue component library for company's internal use. However, I faced some difficulties on building and deploy the project. This component library contains several components inside. And it will finally build by `vue-cli-service build --target lib`. The problem I am facing right now is that I have a component (i.e. called `Audio.vue`), and it will import a .mp3 file inside the component. The component is look like this

```js
<template>
  <audio controls :src="soundSrc" />
</template>

<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

import sound from './assets/sound.mp3';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'Audio',
  props: {},
  setup() {
    return { soundSrc: sound };
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

However, I use this component by serving (`vue-cli-service serve"`) my project is fine. But if I build this project by running `vue-cli-service build --target lib --name project-name-here`. And I use this built version as a git submodule of my library in another vue project by importing `project-name-here.common` built before. The `sound.mp3` import from `'./assets/sound.mp3'` could not be found. It seems it is using a relative path of my another vue project (i.e. `localhost:8080`) instead of the library project

Here is my `vue.config.js`

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: false,
  },
  lintOnSave: false,
  productionSourceMap: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        mediaAsset: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/components/Audio/assets'),
      },
    },
  },
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    const imgRule = config.module.rule('images');
    imgRule
      .use('url-loader')
      .loader('url-loader')
      .tap((options) => Object.assign(options, { limit: Infinity }));

    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg');
    svgRule.uses.clear();

    svgRule
      .test(/\.svg$/)
      .use('svg-url-loader') // npm install --save-dev svg-url-loader
      .loader('svg-url-loader');

    config.module
      .rule('raw')
      .test(/\.txt$/)
      .use('raw-loader')
      .loader('raw-loader');

    config.module
      .rule('media')
      .test(/\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/)
      .use('url-loader')
      .loader('url-loader')
      .tap((options) =>
        Object.assign(options, {
          limit: 4096,
          fallback: {
            loader: 'file-loader',
            options: {
              name: 'media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
            },
          },
        })
      );
  },
};
```

Appreciated for answering this question. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4100#issuecomment-498640958

Comment: @MichalLevý Sorry, I am still a beginner of webpack. Is there any code example for fixing this issue. Thanks.